# Draw centered multiline NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, alignment, deprecated

I would like to draw a centered multiline NSString.
Using

```
- (CGSize)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode alignment:(NSTextAlignment)alignment
```

this works like a charm. Unfortunately, this method is deprecated in iOS 7.
According to Apple's documentation I'm supposed to replace the use of this method with

```
- (void)drawWithRect:(CGRect)rect options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context
```

However, this way the drawn text is only centered if the NSString results in a multiline text when being drawn but it is not centered if it results in a single line text when being drawn.

I passed the following `NSMutableParagraphStyle` via the attributes dictionary:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

I set the `options` to `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` and passed `nil` for `context`.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Best regards!

Comment: Show us your multiline text image.  Actually...  Why do you mention an iOS method when you in fact use the Cocoa tag?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I updated the "cocoa" tag to "cocoa-touch". I tried to insert an image but I was not allowed because I do not have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I updated the description of the problem: The text is only centered if the NSString results in a multiline text when being drawn, but it is not centered if it results in a single line text when being drawn.

Comment: That's exactly what you should expect.  If you have two lines of text and tell your application to center the text string with NSTextAlignmentCenter, then the longer one will be the base, and shorter one will be centered relative to the other.